# Sencha Touch: List sorted on Date not working in Android Emulator

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a list view and I am sorting the items based on date. The sorting is done in Store

```
Ext.define('TechHelp.store.Tickets', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
 config: {
    model: 'TechHelp.model.Ticket',
    autoLoad: true,
    sorters:[{ property: 'OpenDate', direction: 'DESC'}],               
     grouper: {
     sortProperty: 'OpenDate',
        direction: 'DESC',
        groupFn: function (record) { 
            if (record && record.data.OpenDate) {
                return convertDate(record.data.OpenDate);
            } else {
                return '';
            }
        }
    }           
    }
});
```

The convertDate code is

```
function convertDate(rec){
  var formated = Ext.Date.format(new Date(rec),'d-m-Y');
return formated;
}
```

This seems to work fine in the chrome browser, but when I package it as native app and run it in Android Emulator the date appears as nAn and therefore the sorting on the list does not work.

[image: In Chrome]
[image: InAndroidSimulator]

If anyone has faced this issue please let me know how you resolved it

Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the model `TechHelp.model.Ticket`, is  the `type` property of the field `OpenDate` set to **date**?

Comment: no the fields in model are defined as below                           fields : [ 'TicketId', 'Description', 'CustomerId',  'Priority', 'Status',{name : 'OpenDate'}, 'CloseDate', 'Category', 'Comments' ],